# when publishing a dot net core 3.1 application on azure I get a .DbConnectionPool CheckPoolBlockingPeriod exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core

On running a published asp.net core 3.1 on azure cloud am getting a `DbConnectionPool CheckPoolBlockingPeriod exception`, I have read the Microsoft documentation around that area but no solution yet, guidance on this regard is welcome.

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'admin'
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)

Comment: *"Login failed for user 'admin' "* Seems pretty clear. I assume the credentials you passed are incorrect to connect to the SQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a connection string that has to be configured appropriately, and that can be done in Visual Studio. Do the following and publish the app again:

1. Right click on the project in Visual Studio and click on "Publish" in the context menu.
2. In the "Publish" tab under "Summary" click on the edit icon you'll find beside "Configuration" (it's a pencil icon).
3. A publish page appears that has an AppDBContext with a empty field for a connection string.
4. Get into your azure admin panel. Find the database and copy it's connection string and paste it in the empty field in Visual Studio described in step 4 and make sure you set the right user name and password in the connection string.

Let me know if you run in to any problems.